# MySQL performance_schema NULL users

Tags: mysql, percona-server

I was running performance_schema query to check for users performing DDL on our databases, and found a NULL user, which however does not exists when i check the mysql database for users using the query below:

```
select user, host from user;
```

The query that is showing the NULL user accounts when using performance_schema is:

```
SELECT user, host, SUBSTR(event_name, 15) AS event_name, count_star
  FROM performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name
 WHERE count_star > 0 AND
     ( event_name LIKE 'statement/sql/create%'
    OR event_name LIKE 'statement/sql/alter%'
    OR event_name LIKE 'statement/sql/drop%'
    OR event_name LIKE 'statement/sql/rename%'
    OR event_name LIKE 'statement/sql/grant%'
    OR event_name LIKE 'statement/sql/revoke%'
    OR event_name LIKE 'statement/sql/optimize%'
    OR event_name LIKE 'statement/sql/truncate%'
    OR event_name LIKE 'statement/sql/repair%'
    OR event_name LIKE 'statement/sql/check%'
     );
```

Results:

```
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+
| user         | host          | event_name       | count_star |
+--------------+---------------+------------------+------------+
| NULL         | NULL          | create_table     |         50 |
| NULL         | NULL          | alter_table      |         79 |
| NULL         | NULL          | truncate         |         10 |
| NULL         | NULL          | drop_table       |         25 |
| NULL         | NULL          | grant            |          6 |
| NULL         | NULL          | create_db        |          2 |
| NULL         | NULL          | rename_table     |          6 |
| NULL         | NULL          | create_user      |          6 |
| NULL         | NULL          | drop_user        |          6 |
| NULL         | NULL          | create_trigger   |         18 |
| NULL         | NULL          | drop_trigger     |         18 |
| root         | localhost     | create_table     |        919 |
| root         | localhost     | alter_table      |       1918 |
| root         | localhost     | truncate         |         13 |
| root         | localhost     | drop_table       |        850 |
| root         | localhost     | grant            |          3 |
```

So what is this NULL user account?

Comment: Tip:  `AND event_name REGEXP '^statement/sql/(create|alter|drop|rename|grant|revoke|optimize|truncate|repair|check)';`

Comment: I can't explain the `NULL`, but turning on the "general log" and looking at it might give you some more clues.  I'll be interested to hear what you find.

Comment: I too have some NULL user in `SELECT * FROM performance_schema.accounts` so if you have new clues about its signification, please share : ) Doc says ["This is NULL for an internal thread, or for a user session that failed to authenticate."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/5.6/en/accounts-table.html) but then, what would be the "internal thread"?